# the relationship between Returns to Scale and shape of Production Possibility Frontier (PPF)?

Tags: microeconomics, international-trade

Guys any material that discusses the above in detail for a two commodity case?

Comment: PPF is for Production Possibility Frontier (for all non english economists)

Comment: In what context are you interested in it? You mean in the sense of: „if I consume more of A, A will become cheaper“?

Comment: This might help: https://qr.ae/pGLAbN

Comment: @vanya I wanted to understand the geometry of the PPF for a two commodity case like conditions for it to be concave/convex/linear depending on the returns to scale each commodity exhibits.

Answer (score 1):

There is an indirect relationship. PPF size and shape is determined by production functions. Set of production functions $F_i= AK{^0.5}L^{0.5}$ will produce different PPF then set of production functions $F_i= A(K+L)^{0.5}$.

Only some production functions exhibit increasing, decreasing and constant returns to scale. So there is some relationship. However, you can generate so many varied PPF with various production function that it is difficult to exhaustively describe it.

You can see how PPF is calculated in microeconomics textbooks. Frank Microeconomics and Behavior has some examples of PPF for different production functions.

Comment: @Giskard yes production functions do produce PPF. PPF is derived from production functions for goods. If good A has production function $A=10L$ and good B production function $B=L$ then PPF for A and B if country has L=100 is $100 = A/10 + B$. If you change production function for B to $B=10L$ you get new PPF $100=A/10 + B/10$. How else can you get PPF if not by using production functions for goods?

Comment: Note the **emphasis**. Production function**s** can determine a PPF, but **A** production function, what you write about in your answer, cannot.

Comment: @Giskard you could just said so

Comment: I did, and when you asked for clarification, I clarified.